# Flutter change locale for image_picker

Tags: flutter, internationalization, translation, imagepicker

I am using the package image_picker. All works fine except that the locale can not be changed. It is only English.

Is it a way to translate this package?
I've added in my MaterialApp :

```
supportedLocales: [
      const Locale('fr', ''),
    ],
```

But it doesn't change anything for image_picker (it does for other packages like date picker).

Thanks,
Luc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faced the same problem.

And after many hours of searching, it unexpectedly helped in my case. Perhaps it will be useful for someone else.

Edit the file Info.plist manually. By Android Studio or VS Code or other text editor.

Replace

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
```

By

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
  <array>
     <string>ru-RU</string>
     <string>en-US</string>
  </array>
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
  <array>
     <string>ru-RU</string>
     <string>en-US</string>
  </array>
```

Of course, specifying your localization in the format xx-XX and specifying the parameters MaterialApp supportedLocales and localizationsDelegates.